# Implementing UICollectionView horizontally | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am implementing a collection view horizontally, and I want to achieve UI just like in app store.
[image: App store image]

I want to achieve the spacing that look, i.e UICollectionview cell is in the middle, and showing other cells on the sides. What happening to my code is that I am not able to scroll it to the centre.[image: My implementation]

Below is the code I am using to achieve what I did so far.

```
    lazy var cardCollectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .blue
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    return collectionView
}()
```

**Constraints**

```
        cardCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        cardCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        cardCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 42)
        cardCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
```

**CollectionViewDelegate Methods**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! CardCell
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 364, height: 240)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top:0 , left: 25, bottom:0 , right:0)
}
```

Comment: I understand that the best way is to implement an infinite loop and set as selected first time the item on the 1 position of the data source array

Comment: If you are OK with using external libraries, I recommend using **iCarousel** . It is easy to implement  and you will get all functionalities for free. Here is a link :  [cocoapods link](https://cocoapods.org/pods/iCarousel)